# Chart doesn't show Array Values

Tags: c#, arrays, charts, datasource, output

I have a file where stats of the user will be saved. The file has 2 lines. I have an example file that has the following content "23\n48".
I am loading this into a string array and returning it to my chart's DataSource.
Once I made it work but now it doesn't show anything after i changed some properties and pressed ctrl+z to cancel the changes but I am sure nothing has changed on the sourcecode.
Now it stays blank like it's DataSource would be NULL.
I deleted the chart and initialised it again without changing anything on it's properties except setting the chartType to "pie" but didn't help. I checked the chart's source with the debugger and it has the values of the file. But I don't get why it doesn't show me anymore after searching a few hours. I know it works with arrays since I made it once so please don't tell me I could also try with other types like DataTable. I am a bit curious now :P

Here is what I typed:

```
chart1.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("Stats/" + sender.toString());
```

The Method ReadAllLines returns the string array with the values. I also tried it with converting and putting it into an int array but still no results :(

I hope I gave enough informations about my problem.
Sorry if my English is bad. It's not my main language.

Oh, and i am using Visual Studio 2012 and C# as language

Best regards (newbie) ExSynth :)

EDIT **(SOLVED)**:
Here is a bigger snippet of my sourcecode:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("Languages")) { Directory.CreateDirectory("Languages"); }
    if (!Directory.Exists("Stats")) { Directory.CreateDirectory("Stats"); }
    RefreshLanguages();
}

private void spracheHinzufügenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("Languages")) { Directory.CreateDirectory("Languages"); }
    Add_Language Add_Language = new Add_Language();
    Add_Language.ShowDialog();
    RefreshLanguages();
}

private void RefreshLanguages()
{
    int j = spracheAuswählenToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) { spracheAuswählenToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.RemoveAt(0); }

    string[] fileListWithPath = Directory.GetFiles("Languages");
    for (int i = 0; i < fileListWithPath.Length; i++)
    {
        ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileListWithPath[i]));
        item.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Abfragen);
        spracheAuswählenToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
    }
}

private void Abfragen(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbl_Language.Text = sender.ToString();
    chart1.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("Stats/" + sender.ToString());
    chart1.DataBind();
}
```

EDIT:

I solved my problem. I couldn't find anything useful on the internet so I looked up in my old sourcecodes and found this:

```
    chart_History.DataSource = table; // sets the datasource of the chart to the datatable which was filled above
    chart_History.Series[0].XValueMember = table.Columns["index"].ToString();  // sets the datasource of the X-Axis of the chart
    chart_History.Series[0].YValueMembers = table.Columns[Convert.ToString(cmbBox_List.SelectedIndex + 1)].ToString(); // sets the datasource of the Y-Axis of the chart
    chart_History.Series[0].LegendText = cmbBox_List.SelectedItem.ToString(); // Sets the string of the legend to the selected item of the combobox
    chart_History.DataBind(); // Finally binds the Information to the chart
```

Appearently I have to declare the X and Y Axis...
So I HAD deleted something by mistake by pressing CTRL+Z...
But I think I'll use DataTable instead. It's too much mess with Arrays.
Thanks for your help.
I hope this will help someone else in the future :)

Comment: Is this a Microsoft charting control ? Give example of what File.ReadAllLines("Stats/" + sender.toString()) returns.

Comment: @sarin
The debugger shows following:

chart1.DataSource[0] = 23 (string)
chart1.DataSource[1] = 48 (string)

These values are correct. They are in the file and were returned correctly into the DataSource.
Yes, I think it's that Microsoft chart control since I use Visual Studio 2012 which is from Microsoft. I din't import any foreign controls or classes.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following after?:

```
chart1.DataBind();
```

This is an old post but it maybe helpful: [Data Binding Microsoft Chart Control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx)

Comment: I already tried DataBind().
Still doesn't work.
I'll check out that link.

Comment: I edited my first post. Watch there :)
Thanks for your help.

And sorry, I used german words and didn't comment anything. It's just a project for myself so I didn't care much...

Comment: I solved it. See my first post for the solution.
Thank you :)